# image rename function in php

Tags: php, image, resize

I have this code which generates me two images.

What it does is generate images with the names `small_test.jpg.JPG` and `test.jpg.JPG`

What I need is for the first name generated to be `test_s.jpg` and the second one to just be `test.jpg`.

This requires changes in the functions that I need help with.

```
function setFile($src = null) {
  $this->ext = strtoupper(pathinfo($src, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
  if(is_file($src) && ($this->ext == "JPG" OR $this->ext == "JPEG")) {
    $this->img_r = ImageCreateFromJPEG($src);
  } elseif(is_file($src) && $this->ext == "PNG") {
    $this->img_r = ImageCreateFromPNG($src);
  } elseif(is_file($src) && $this->ext == "GIF") {
    $this->img_r = ImageCreateFromGIF($src);
  }
  $this->img_w = imagesx($this->img_r);
  $this->img_h = imagesy($this->img_r);
}

function resize($largestSide = 100) {
  $width = imagesx($this->img_r);
  $height = imagesy($this->img_r);
  $newWidth = 0;
  $newHeight = 0;

  if($width > $height){
    $newWidth = $largestSide;
    $newHeight = $height * ($newWidth / $width);
  } else {
    $newHeight = $largestSide;
    $newWidth = $width * ($newHeight / $height);
  }

  $this->dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor($newWidth, $newHeight);
  imagecopyresampled( $this->dst_r, 
                      $this->img_r, 
                      0, 0, 0, 0, 
                      $newWidth, $newHeight, 
                      $width, $height);
  $this->img_r = $this->dst_r;
  $this->img_h = $newHeight;
  $this->img_w = $newWidth;
}

function createFile($output_filename = null) {
  if($this->ext == "JPG" OR $this->ext == "JPEG") {
    imageJPEG($this->dst_r, $this->uploaddir.$output_filename.'.'.$this->ext, $this->quality);
  } elseif($this->ext == "PNG") {
    imagePNG($this->dst_r, $this->uploaddir.$output_filename.'.'.$this->ext);
  } elseif($this->ext == "GIF") {
    imageGIF($this->dst_r, $this->uploaddir.$output_filename.'.'.$this->ext);
  }
  return $output_filename;
}

function setUploadDir($dirname) {
  $this->uploaddir = $dirname;
}

function flush() {
  $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
  $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
  $targetFile = str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
  $filename = $_FILES['Filedata']['name']; 
  $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  $thumbnail = basename($filename,'.' .$ext) . '_s.' . $ext;    

  imagedestroy($this->dst_r);
  unlink($targetFile);
  imagedestroy($this->img_r);
}

}

$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
$targetFile = str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
$filename = $_FILES['Filedata']['name']; 
$ext = pathinfo($FileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$thumbnail = basename($FileName,'.' .$ext) . '_s.' . $ext;  
move_uploaded_file ($tempFile, $targetFile);

$image = new Image();
$image->setFile($targetFile);
$image->setUploadDir($targetPath);
$image->resize(640);
$small_file = $image->createFile('small_'.$filename);
$image->resize(100);
$large_file = $image->createFile($filename);
$image->flush();
}
```

Comment: This is a lot of code. Where exactly is it not working?

Comment: What error do you get ? on which line ? what's the input ? please read [*this*](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: is it just the names you want to change, or is it not uploading?

Comment: Well i don't get any error, i just don't know how to do what i need... i mean in order to achieve it i know i must change the setFile and createFile function, i just don't know how to change it to my needs..

Comment: I just need to change the names, that's all!

Comment: It uploads great! I just don't know how to change those two functions..

Comment: `$small_file = $image->createFile('small_'.$filename);` here your thumb is created. Just play arround with the name you pass to the function (`'small_'.$filename`).

Comment: Hey Yoshi, thanks, well i know that, and trust me i've been playing around for two days and still nothing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is so wrong I cannot fix it without recoding it completely.

You should give: http://phpthumb.gxdlabs.com a try. It is the one I use and it is performant, bugless and security aware.

It can do a lot of stuff and I would strongly recommend using this instead of trying to make your own library.

Comment: yes.. i've been seeing it! i was using something i found from uploadify, i just look the code you gave me, and it actually still won't give the output!...

Comment: @Al_12 Edited again since I realised a mistake

Comment: Hey thanks so much for trying to help me :) i appreciate it! I tried this one but it doesn't create an image...

Comment: @Al_12 Yea it will only send on the right path, at the end of the day you will need to fix the bugs in it, but the structure is right.

Comment: @Al_12 Actually I would ditch your code completely and use: http://phpthumb.gxdlabs.com Since it is much better